# How to make Xcode display a string representation for user class?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

Consider the following class:

```
class CalculatorButton: CalculatorButtonProtocol, CustomStringConvertible {
    var type: CalculatorButtonType
    var description: String {
        return label
    }
    
    let label: String
    init(_ label: String, type: CalculatorButtonType) {
        self.label = label
        self.type = type
    }
    
    func action(n1: String, n2: String?) -> String {
        fatalError("Not implemented")
    }
    
    func format(_ n: Float) -> String {
        if n == floor(n) {
            return String(Int(n))
        }
        
        return String(n)
    }
}
```

While debugging using breakpoints, it's very useful to see a string representation of a class in the debugger window. For the above, I'd like to see the label. However, Xcode shows the reference of the button instance instead. People are saying that adopting `CustomStringConvertible` protocol gives a class human-readable representation, but that didn't help.

GitHub link: https://github.com/asarkar/ios-bootcamp/tree/master/Calculator-SwiftUI

[image]

Comment: just print your button

Comment: @LeoDabus I don’t want temporary print statements in the code; there has to be a better way. Or may be not, Apple might not have figured out debugging yet.

Comment: They probably downvoted it because you attached a screenshot of your code instead of the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class implement `CustomDebugStringConvertible`, this will print your custom representation instead of the instance address.

```swift
class CalculatorButton: CustomDebugStringConvertible {

    // ...

    var debugDescription: String {
        label
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, I just tested it with `po myClass` and a got the `debugDescription` printed out in the lldb debugger window.

Comment: I've updated the question with the GitHub link to the project, it only has few files. You can download it and run the test to reproduce the issue.